# Will my phone be able to update to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: update, 7.x

I currently have a Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango or 7.5) and want to know if I can update it to the upcoming Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Microsoft announced an update will be available for current Windows Phones. The update will be named Windows Phone 7.8.  There will be no way to fully update your device to Windows Phone 8.

Also, the update will be sent out using the Over the Air technology.

UPDATE 
Windows Phone 8.1 is now available to the public via an OTA update as part of the Preview for Developers program.

You can only do this update from an 8.0 device, [this is a great WPCentral article](http://www.wpcentral.com/preview-for-developers) highlighting the new OS and how to get it

Win10 Mobile UPDATE - (March-2015)

Now that a new version is available, there may be questions of "Can I go from WP7 to WP10", unfortunately this will **not be supported for Windows Phone 7.x devices**. . You can now get a preview of Windows 10 Mobile (the next version of Windows Phone). It's relatively easy to install, but is limited to a few devices right now [Go here to read the FAQ and installation instructions.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq-right-for-me-phone)

A word of caution, I recommend not updating your phone until the build has become a little more stable, however I totally recommend putting in on a spare phone or go buy a throw-away Lumia 635 for $50 to install it on.

Comment: Here is the link to the WPCentral article on the topic http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-unveils-windows-phone-78-update-legacy-hardware

Comment: So the Windows 10 can be installed in Windows (Phone) devices with Windows 7.8? Someone already did it successfully?

Comment: @FabioSilva He didn't mention that. The Question title talk about Windows Prone 8 so its somewhat confusing. But "No", you will not be able to install it in pre Windows Phone 8 hardware.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot upgrade a Windows Phone 7.x device to Windows Phone 8. This can be confirmed by a [post](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Nokia-Lumia/Will-windows8-be-available-for-lumia-610/td-p/1557358) in the Nokia Forums.

> Windows Phone 8 is a generation shift from Windows Phone 7.5 and will
>   not be available for current devices due to the hardware requirements
>   for Windows Phone 8. That said, an update will be made available which
>   will, amongst other things, provide the new start screen to current
>   Windows Phone devices.

Answer (score 4):

The Lumia 610 was launched as a Windows Phone 7 device. Windows Phone 7 is based on the Windows CE architecture (CE stands for Compact Embedded- this was an operating system that Microsoft deployed to embedded systems such as mobile phones).

Unfortunately, shortly after Windows Phone 7 was launched, Microsoft went down the route of unifying all of it's platforms (desktop, phone, etc.) and hence the next version of Windows Phone i.e. Windows Phone 8 was not based on Windows CE but on Windows NT (just like the desktop Windows 8). This is why Windows Phone 7 devices cannot run Windows Phone 8 OS (different architectures).

To appease buyers of Windows Phone 7 devices, Microsoft released Windows Phone 7.8 as the final update to Windows Phone 7 devices.

If you haven't already upgraded to this version, [take a look at this page by Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/lumia-software-update/).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no way to upgrade windows phone 7.x to 8 or 10, because windows phone 7 is based on Windows CE, and 8 or 10 is based on windows NT.
But there's an upgrade named windows phone 7.8. It only changes start menu of your phone as it of windows phone 8.
Additionally, Microsoft stopped support of windows phone 7, so i recommend u to change it to newer version.

Comment: @NiravMadariya As far as I know Windows phone 7 OS runs on a different kernal and cannot be updated to Windows phone 8 or Windows 10 mobile. What you say is completely wrong. can you cite sources from where you heard?

Comment: @NiravMadariya You can find references [here in my answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12635/18061) that there will be no second wave of Windows 10 mobile update. You can also find MS's explanation why there will be no windows 10 update for older devices.