# When Lumia 610 will be updated to OS 8?

Tags: lumia, update

I am owning Lumia 610 and is there any way to know when My phone gets OS 8 update?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upgrade a Windows Phone 7.x device to Windows Phone 8. This can be confirmed by a [post](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Nokia-Lumia/Will-windows8-be-available-for-lumia-610/td-p/1557358) in the Nokia Forums.

> Windows Phone 8 is a generation shift from Windows Phone 7.5 and will
>   not be available for current devices due to the hardware requirements
>   for Windows Phone 8. That said, an update will be made available which
>   will, amongst other things, provide the new start screen to current
>   Windows Phone devices.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but I think your answer would be worth posting on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/676/will-my-phone-be-able-to-update-to-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0):

The Lumia 610 was launched as a Windows Phone 7 device. Windows Phone 7 is based on the Windows CE architecture (CE stands for Compact Embedded- this was an operating system that Microsoft deployed to embedded systems such as mobile phones).

Unfortunately, shortly after Windows Phone 7 was launched, Microsoft went down the route of unifying all of it's platforms (desktop, phone, etc.) and hence the next version of Windows Phone i.e. Windows Phone 8 was not based on Windows CE but on Windows NT (just like the desktop Windows 8). This is why Windows Phone 7 devices cannot run Windows Phone 8 OS (different architectures).

To appease buyers of Windows Phone 7 devices, Microsoft released Windows Phone 7.8 as the final update to Windows Phone 7 devices.

If you haven't already upgraded to this version, [take a look at this page by Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/lumia-software-update/).

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but I think your answer would be worth posting on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/676/will-my-phone-be-able-to-update-to-windows-phone-8