# is it possible to install "preview for developers" on my nokia lumia 610

Tags: lumia, 7.x

I really want to have windows phone 8.1 on my Nokia lumia 610 but is it possible to install the preview for developers app or windows insider on a lumia 610

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Lumia 610 will be updated to OS 8?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/when-lumia-610-will-be-updated-to-os-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my phone be able to update to Windows Phone 8?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/676/will-my-phone-be-able-to-update-to-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Lumia 610 is a Windows phone 7.x phone, it's not possible to install neither the preview for developpers, neither any version of Windows phone 8

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 should already be available for your Lumia 610. You don't need the Developer's Preview. According to this [source](http://mynokialumia.com/how-to-update-my-lumia-610-to-windows-phone-8-1/), in order to upgrade to 8.1:

**Step 1**: Go to **Settings** > **Phone Update** and tapping **Check for    Updates**.

**Step 2**: To start installing the updates, tap on the    notification message and follow up the instruction shown on your    phone.

**Step 3**: The update should usually take around 15-30 minutes,    but a major update might take up to 2 hours to complete the    installation process depending upon you phone model. You would not be    able to use your Lumia 610 during the update procedure. You should    answer all the update prompts whenever asked to. Don’t panic if the    Lumia 610 restarts several times during the update installation, as    it is quite normal.

---

As for Windows 10, according to [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/preview-supported-phones), there's no Insider's Preview yet.

Comment: This is not true because a Nokia lumia 610 takes zune software and it has no way of updating using OTA by the phone and I don't trust the mynokialumia.com website